# how to group a special character and a letter in regex in ruby?

Tags: regex, ruby

I have regular expression like this in ruby

```
%r{
  (ST)
  ([A-Z]) ?
  (#{A_VAL})
  -?
  (T)?
}x
```

Now ,I don't want my regex to accept any string that ends with "-" .So, for example it should accept 
1)"STCA1-T" 
2)"STCA1T"  
But it shouldn't accept "STCA1-"

Comment: Try `(?:-?(T))?` instead of `-?(T)?`. BTW, are you sure you did not miss the anchors like `\A` at the start and `\z` at the end? Try `/\A(ST)([A-Z])?(CA1)(?:-?(T))?\z/`, the anchors are crucial here as they signal the start/end of string.

Comment: Do you really need all these capture groups?They slow down the process.

Comment: @Toto any other suggestions ? how can i handle this in a better way ?

Comment: @code_t Toto means 1) remove unnecessary (redundant) groups, 2) convert those groupings you need to accommodate alternative patterns into non-capturing groups.

Comment: You could insert `(?!.*-\z).*` at the beginning of the regex. Note that, since you are defining the regex in free-spacing mode (`/x`) all spaces will be stripped out before the regex is parsed, including that space in `([A-Z]) ?`. If that spaces is to be retained it must be escaped (`\ `), put in a character class (`[ ]`) or, if matching a whitespace is OK, replaced with `\s`, `\p{Space}` or `[[:space']]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/\AST[A-Z]?(#{A_VAL})(?:-?T)?\z/
```

**Details**

- `\A` - start of string
- `ST` - an `ST` substring
- `[A-Z]?` - an optional ASCII letter
- `(#{A_VAL})` - Group 1 (if there is a single alternative, just one string, and you do not need this value later, you may omit the capturing parentheses): a pattern inside `A_VAL` variable
- `(?:-?T)?` - an optional non-capturing group that matches an optional `-` and an obligatory `T` (i.e. it matches `-T` or `T` 1 or 0 times)
- `\z` - end of string.